# Case statements will support raise exception or not?

Tags: postgresql

```
 case when $1 is null then raise exception 'Please enter $1'
      when $2 is null then raise exception 'Please enter $2' 
 end;
```

Is it will work please can any give me answer

Answer (score 5):

Best I'm aware, it won't. The `case` operator is for expression branching, as in one-liner statements that returns a value. For more complicated things and raising exceptions, use `if … then … end if;`.

Answer (score 1):

You can verify on sqlfiddle.com if you like. I did, and it certainly did not work in postgres. Raise is a pl/pgsql command, not an sql command.