# Raise exception if a specific column value is null

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to get exception for the case where a specific column is null in **PostgreSQL**. I am planning to add a new column which shouldn't be null, so i will fill the previous records accordingly before adding not null constraint. But also need to be sure as no nulls left behind. Anyway...

I have a sample here on [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0d176/2) but no matter how i tried, it always return syntax error about EXCEPTION or IF for other attempts.
What i am trying to get is an exception WHEN any of the records.educator column is null.

Is there any way to achive this.
Thanks in advance.
Also example schema can be found below if sqlFiddle frogs.

```
CREATE TABLE courses(
    course_id serial primary key,
    course_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    description VARCHAR(500),
    published_date date,
    educator VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO 
    courses(course_name, description, published_date)
VALUES
    ('PostgreSQL for Developers','A complete PostgreSQL for Developers','2020-07-13'),
    ('PostgreSQL Admininstration','A PostgreSQL Guide for DBA',NULL),
    ('PostgreSQL High Performance',NULL,NULL),
    ('PostgreSQL Bootcamp','Learn PostgreSQL via Bootcamp','2013-07-11'),
    ('Mastering PostgreSQL','Mastering PostgreSQL in 21 Days','2012-06-30');
```

My example query is like below:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 0 THEN RAISE EXCEPTION 'ERROR: Some records in the "educator" column have null values' END 
FROM (
    SELECT educator FROM courses WHERE educator IS NULL
) AS sq;
```

Comment: 1) There  is no `RAISE` SQL command per [SQL Commands](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-commands.html). That needs to be done in `plpgsql` per [Report Errors](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RAISE).  2) Why do this any way?  Just do `SELECT count(educator) FROM courses WHERE educator IS NULL`. If the count > 0 then you know there are NULL values.

Comment: If you want to force an exception in plain SQL you could do something like: `select case when count(*) > 0 then 1/(count(*)-count(*)) end from courses where educator is null;`. This will result in a `ERROR:  division by zero` exception.

Comment: Does this help ? [Case statements will support raise exception or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20186109/case-statements-will-support-raise-exception-or-not)

Comment: @SRJ The reference will not accomplish what OP wants. `Raise Exception` **cannot** be used in SQL. It is strictly a `plpgsql` construct.

Comment: @Belayer yes but it will help clear that this is not possible currently in postgresql with case.

Comment: why not just `alter table courses alter column educator set not null;` ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all comments. They really helped. I used PL/pgSQL solution. Here is the solution that i get.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_educator() RETURNS VOID AS $$
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM courses WHERE courses.educator IS NULL) THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'The educator column cannot be null in the courses table';
    END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT check_educator();
```

And then

```
SELECT check_educator();
```

Btw this doesn't work on db-fiddle, but It works in Jetbrains SQL console.